# how to check if foreach loop empty when using json and php

Tags: php, json

i'm using JSON to get data and then PHP to display. so... 
i'm showing everything available to a person and i want to echo a message when the loop is blank/empty that "there's nothing available" because right now it just shows a blank screen when there is no data... any ideas??

```
<? 
foreach($json['available'] as $r) { 
echo '<li><a href="url.php?id='.$r['id'].'">' .$r['item'].'</a></li>'; 
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `if` statement and check if `$json['available']` is empty with [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty).

```
if( empty( $json['available'])) {
    echo '<li>No items are available</li>';
} else {
    foreach($json['available'] as $r) { 
        echo '<li><a href="url.php?id='.$r['id'].'">' .$r['item'].'</a></li>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also you count($json['available']) instead of empty($json['available'])

Comment: @nickb i tested again and now i get the msg that no items available every time . even there r items available - any ideas?

Comment: @Azukah - Yeah, available has a typo, which is one of the reasons why you shouldn't just copy and paste code from the Internet. :P I've fixed the typo.

Comment: so sorry mate @nickb . it's been a long day since yesterday . nee dosme sleep. i had the field misspelled . thanks again and sorry for freakign out.

Answer (score 1):

Use [empty](http://php.net/empty) to check if $json contains something or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$json['available']` is going to be an empty array at worst:

```
if (!$json['available']) {
    echo "nothing to show!";
}
else {
    // your current code
}
```

If it's possible that `$json['available']` might not even exist, a more "heavy-handed" alternative is

```
if (empty($json['available'])) {
    echo "nothing to show!";
}
```